# Dispatching redux action has long run time

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have been working with an application using react and redux. I ran into a performance issue and started doing some digging. After a lot of tracing and timing things, I noticed something I thought was unusual. When dispatching an action, using the `useDispatch` hook, the dispatch takes much longer than I would have guessed to return.

Here is how I measured the runtime:

```js
const partialDar = {
    coordinates,
    displayName: appUser.displayName,
    formattedAddress: property.place.formattedAddress,
    isCardinal: Boolean(property.cardinal),
    propertyId: property.propertyId,
    senderId: appUser.userId,
    serviceProviderId: appUser.serviceProviderId
};

const startTime = Date.now();
dispatch(startDar(partialDar))
const endTime = Date.now();
console.log(`${endTimer-startTimer}ms`);
```

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import uuidv4 from "uuid/v4";

import * as constants from "../../../constants";

const patrolModeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "patrolMode",
  initialState: {
    enabled: false,
    options: {
      darsNote: "",
      cooldown: constants.patrols.defaultCooldown,
      includeCardinals: false
    },
    darsInProgress: {
      byPropertyId: {}
    },
    inBoundPropertiesOnCooldown: {
      byId: {}
    }
  },
  reducers: {
    enable: (state, action) => {
      const { darsNote, cooldown, includeCardinals } = action.payload;
      state.enabled = true;
      state.options = {
        darsNote: darsNote ? darsNote : constants.patrols.defaultMessage,
        cooldown,
        includeCardinals
      };
    },
    disable: (state, action) => {
      state.enabled = false;
      state.darsInProgress.byPropertyId = {};
    },
    startDar: (state, action) => {
      const startTime = Date.now();
      const {
        coordinates,
        displayName,
        formattedAddress,
        isCardinal,
        propertyId,
        senderId,
        serviceProviderId
      } = action.payload;
      if (state.enabled && !state.darsInProgress.byPropertyId[propertyId]) {
        state.darsInProgress.byPropertyId[propertyId] = {
          displayName,
          formattedAddress,
          isCardinal,
          notes: state.darsNote
            ? state.darsNote
            : constants.patrols.defaultMessage,
          patrolId: uuidv4(),
          propertyId,
          senderId,
          serviceProviderId,
          startCoordinates: coordinates,
          startTime: Date.now()
        };
      }
      const endTime = Date.now();
      console.log(`reducer ${endTimer-startTimer}ms`);
    },
    endDar: (state, action) => {
      const { propertyId } = action.payload;
      if (state.enabled) {
        delete state.darsInProgress.byPropertyId[propertyId];
      }
    }
  }
});

const { actions, reducer } = patrolModeSlice;

export const { disable, enable, endDar, startDar } = actions;

export default reducer;

export const selectEnabled = state => state.patrolMode.enabled;
export const selectOptions = state => state.patrolMode.options;
export const selectDarsInProgress = state => state.patrolMode.darsInProgress;
```

I would have expected timer surrounding the dispatch to show `0ms` or `1ms` as the output, but after measuring a bunch of different action dispatches, the measured time varies widely between `25ms` and `1000ms`.

In addition, the timer inside the actual reducer ran in under `1ms`. What is causing all of this extra overhead?

Comment: Can you share some code samples?

Comment: this is telling us nothing. Who knows what magic is happening in testAction :)

Comment: Attaching a Chrome performance trace capture file might help.  Also, make sure that you're doing any profiling against a production build, not a dev build, as dev builds generally add overhead.

Comment: I edited the question to include more information.